# Vb6 project not starting

Tags: vba, vb6

Added a new command in my project and got an "insufficient memory" error then the project closed. I try opening the file by double clicking on it and it closes as soon as it opens. I'm using windows xp.

Comment: Anything useful in the Windows event log?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Check the project folder for error logs, that where VB6 puts them if required (else they don't exist). Open each file (ie frm, bas, ctl, cls) in VB6 as individual files. That should tell you the problem one.

Comment: What version of vb6? When I used the student edition I got those errors too, but now when I use enterprise I dont get that problem.

Comment: And by the way, do you have lots of controls and forms in that project? That could be another cause for the error.

Comment: I do have lots of forms in that project. I can open everything but the dataenviroment, error says "can't read". Nothing on the event log no error log. Using vb6 enterprise.

Comment: What exactly is the new command you added?  That's probably what caused it, and without knowing what it was it's impossible to help you.

Comment: Have you ruled out the possibility of a stack overflow error?

Answer (score 0):

I opened the .vbp file with notepad and deleted the .dsr file I added, proyect is working now. Thanks for all replies

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by 'command' ?
Is it a control ? (which control) ?

If your form has a lot of controls, you can convert some of them to Control Arrays 
For example find all the Labels that do not have events etc, and give them all the same name, and set the Index for each control to 0, 1, 2 etc

Additionally, you can use Control Arrays for control that have events.

Comment: Would control arrays really save memory?